# How do I correctly interpolate controller name and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a method that dynamically assigns the controller name and action for all my controllers in `application_controller`, but I can't seem to interpolate the value correctly. If I hardcode what I want, it will render the correct page so it seems to only be the interpolation that's the problem.

This is what I have:

```
def authorized
  render 'pages/unauthorized' unless Policy.new(current_user.role)."#{controller_name.singularize}_#{action_name}"
end
```

which returns

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting '(' ...Policy.new(current_user.role)."#{controller_name.singularize... ... ^
```

If I wrap the whole thing in `( )` then the syntax error goes away, but then I get a:

```
undefined method `call' for #<Policy:0x00007ff29ced4ae0 @role="user">
```

if I hardcode `Policy.new(current_user.role).wiki_show` then it correctly checks resolves. What am I doing wrong in the interpolation?

Comment: Give it a try to public_send `Policy.new(current_user.role).public_send("#{controller_name.singularize}_#{action_name}")`.

Comment: Was exactly what I needed, thank you. I didn't realize that you can't just interpolate a method name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Object#public_send`:

> public_send(string [, args...]) → obj
>
> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments
>   specified. Unlike send, #public_send calls public methods only. When
>   the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a
>   symbol.

It works like:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    'bar'
  end
end

bar_method = 'bar'
p Foo.new.public_send(bar_method) # "bar"
```

So you could do

```
Policy.new(current_user.role).public_send("#{controller_name.singularize}_#{action_name}")
```